# chmod is owned by root and permissions are 220

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions

If `chmod` has user:group permissions of `root:root`, and has the permissions of `220`, can a root user restore the execute permissions?

In general, how those chicken-egg problems should be resolved from a Unix architecture perspective?

I always thought, that the root user could do everything, even execute files with `000` permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In general , how those chicken-egg problems should be resolved from Unix architecture perspective?

If you break your chmod by changing its permissions (for whatever reason), you can still fix it by calling the underlying OS hooks.  For example:

```
vagrant@vagrant-base-tfisher:~$ sudo -i
root@vagrant-base-tfisher:~# which chmod
/bin/chmod
root@vagrant-base-tfisher:~# chown 220 /bin/chmod 
root@vagrant-base-tfisher:~# ls -la /bin/chmod 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 220 root 51760 Apr  1  2012 /bin/chmod
root@vagrant-base-tfisher:~# chmod 220 /bin/chmod 
root@vagrant-base-tfisher:~# ls -la /bin/chmod 
--w--w---- 1 root root 51760 Apr  1  2012 /bin/chmod
root@vagrant-base-tfisher:~# chmod 755 /bin/chmod 
-bash: /bin/chmod: Permission denied
root@vagrant-base-tfisher:~# irb
irb(main):002:0> File.chmod(0755,'/bin/chmod')                                                                                                                                                              
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> quit
root@vagrant-base-tfisher:~# ls -la /bin/chmod 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51760 Apr  1  2012 /bin/chmod
```

Comment: Great! That what i was wondering about. Thank you!

Comment: No problem at all.  Keep in mind that while I did the example in ruby, it's just as trivial to do with other linux built-in commands, such as `cat` or `sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a pretty easy way to recover from this as root using only basic tools:

```
mv /bin/chmod /bin/chmod.wrongperms
cp -p /bin/cat /bin/chmod
cat /bin/chmod.wrongperms >! /bin/chmod
rm /bin/chmod.wrongperms
```

Copying another executable (`cat` here, by way of example) with `-p` preserves the 755 permissions, and `cat`ing the contents of `chmod` into it doesn't change the permissions.

Comment: Ah, yeah , that is a easiest solution , i was looking something like next comment, about calls that are hidden underneath chmod command.  Thank you for answer ).